# Mysql min and max of timed series data

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression, window-functions

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE readings (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  date timestamp NOT NULL,
  value int NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0001, '2023-02-22 10:00:00', '12');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0002, '2023-02-22 10:10:00', '13');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0003, '2023-02-22 10:20:00', '15');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0004, '2023-02-22 10:30:00', '11');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0005, '2023-02-22 10:40:00', '10');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0006, '2023-02-22 10:50:00', '11');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0007, '2023-02-22 11:00:00', '12');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0008, '2023-02-22 11:10:00', '14');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (0009, '2023-02-22 11:20:00', '13');
INSERT INTO readings VALUES (00010, '2023-02-22 11:30:00', '8');
-- fetch 
SELECT min(date), max(date) FROM readings WHERE VALUE >= 12 group by date
```

I want an answer of the lowest (min) and latest (max) time for each batch of dates whereby the value is over 12.

```
min                       max
-- 2023-02-22 10:00:00 -- 2023-02-22 10:20:00
-- 2023-02-22 11:00:00 -- 2023-02-22 11:20:00
```

I'm not convinced this can be done with SQL alone! Can anyone prove me wrong? The real dates are not quite so cleanly 10 mins apart.

https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yyvzwwbj

Comment: What is "*batch of dates*"? How is it to be determined?

Comment: Do you want the MIN and MAX over the same `value` field? If so, you should `GROUP BY value`, not date.

Comment: Dates are roughly every 10 mins (but not exactly)- they're temperature sensor readings. A 'batch' is a set of contiguous dates over the threshold (12)- I want the min and max of each.

Comment: where contiguous is by defined by date?  or id?  or either?   if date, are dates unique?

Comment: contiguous by date, dates are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` window function to create the groups/batches that you want and then aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, SUM(value < 12) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp FROM readings)
SELECT MIN(date) min_date,
       MAX(date) max_date
FROM cte
WHERE value >= 12
GROUP BY grp;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ao5gqFSi).